# Implement Datatables responsive details display with Ajax data

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-modal, responsive

I want to implement Datatable's [responsive details with Bootstrap modal](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html) but it doesn't work for me.  The first thing I noticed is that the "plus-sign" does not appear on the first column of my table.  I'm not sure if this is because I'm using ajax data and need additional parameters that the example doesn't show or because I've added an auto number as my first column.

Here is the table HTML:

```
<table id="users" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" data-conf="@Model.ExtraVM.DialogMsg" data-title="@Model.ExtraVM.DialogTitle" data-btnok="@Model.ExtraVM.Button1" data-btncancel="@Model.ExtraVM.Button2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Model.HeadingVM.Col1</th>
                            <th>@Model.HeadingVM.Col2</th>
                            <th>@Model.HeadingVM.Col3</th>
                            <th>@Model.HeadingVM.Col4</th>
                            <th>@Model.HeadingVM.Col5</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var t = $("#users").DataTable({
                responsive: {
                    details: {
                        display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                            header: function (row) {
                                var data = row.data();
                                return 'Details for ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1];
                            }
                        }),
                        renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
                            tableClass: 'table'
                        })
                    }
                },
                columnDefs: [{
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false,
                    "targets": 0
                }],
                order: [[1, 'asc']],
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/users",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "id"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "firstName"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "lastName"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "userName"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye' data-id='" + data + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#dataPopup'></i></a> | <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-pencil js-edit' data-id='" + data + "'></i></a> | <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-trash js-delete' data-id='" + data + "'></i></a>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
                t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                    cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
                });
            }).draw();

            $("#users").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
                var btn = $(this);
                var confirm = btn.parents("table").attr("data-conf");
                var dialogTitle = btn.parents("table").attr("data-title");
                var btnOK = btn.parents("table").attr("data-btnOk");
                var btnCancel = btn.parents("table").attr("data-btnCancel");

                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: confirm,
                    title: dialogTitle,
                    buttons: {
                        main: {
                            label: btnCancel,
                            className: "btn-default",
                            callback: function () {
                                var result = "false";
                            }
                        },
                        success: {
                            label: btnOK,
                            className: "btn-primary",
                            callback: function () {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/api/users/" + btn.attr("data-id"),
                                    method: "DELETE",
                                    success: function () {
                                        btn.parents("tr").remove();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });



    </script>
}
```

This is how my tables looks (as you can see, the plus-sign is missing):

[image]

Comment: Are you loading all the CSS/JS files mentioned in the example you referenced?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the exact same ones they use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine. Plus sign only appears when viewing area is small enough and one of the columns become hidden.

There is no setting to force `(+)` sign to appear but you can use a trick with extra empty column and class `none` on it which will force column to always be hidden. See [Class logic](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) for more details.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym6vsjft/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: So it seems that adding an extra column makes the plus sign appear.  So maybe that's the key.  The plus sign is there to reveal hidden data!  But using your code, my table displayed ALL 9 columns.  Somehow in your example it only displayed 4 columns and hid 3. How did you do that?  I don't see where you're hiding columns in your code.

Comment: Correction:  My table is ATTEMPTING to display all 9 columns.  It doesn't actually display the data in them because of an error:  Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.

Comment: OK I understand this now.  It's a RESPONSIVE feature meaning if there is not enough space to fit all the columns the table will auto-hide the last columns until it does fit.  And when it does hide columns THEN it adds the plus sign.  I was hoping to for something else completely but maybe I can work with it...

Comment: Hey. Is it possible to expand only on + icon and not the entire cell.

Comment: @AdityaGupta, yes, see [`responsive.details.target`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.target) option.

Comment: Cool. So I can modify the selector using target. But I want to select the ::before element which can be selected. How should I go about that ? Should I make my own class with ::before element or something like that ?